# Unable to upload image to S3 via Beanstalk but working in local server

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3

I deployed My Springboot Application in Aws Elasticbeanstalk. In my application i have a module to upload an profile picture and i am saving it in Aws S3,its working fine in local server,but not working in Elasticbeanstalk.I am getting Permission Denied Error.Any One Please help me to solve this issue.
[aws elastic beanstalk logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEsOK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check if your instance profile has permissions to upload to S3. I suppose locally you are using Secret and Access keys which have access to s3. However on the ec2 instance started by elasticbeanstalk probably has no permissions to s3.

Checkout https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-instanceprofile.html for more details on how to configure the role for your instance.

Hope this helps!